# Validation alert in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

There is a user list in my Node-Express-Mongoose app. I need to click on the Update link to open a modal and update the user-info by clicking on the save changes button on the modal. Screenshot below:

[image: Modal]

Whenever i submit the form in the modal without any info, it doesn't alert me.
below is the javascript for the same:

```js
$(document)
  .on('click', '.update_user', function(e) { //click on update link
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#edit_user').unbind('click');
    $('#edit_user').click(function() { //click on save changes button


      var user_name = $("#input_name").val();
      var user_age = $("#input_age").val();

      if (user_name == '' && user_age == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Fields");
        return false;
      }

      var user_data = {
        user_name: user_name,
        user_age: user_age
      };


      $.ajax({
        url: '/users/update_user',
        type: 'post',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user_data),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
          console.log(data);
          load_users();
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

This is the EJS file:

```html
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="openModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update User :</h4>
      </div>


      <div class="modal-body">

        <!--  <form>
          Name:<input id="nameId" name="modal_username" type="text" value="" size="40"> <br>Age:<input id="ageId" size="3" name="modal_age" type="number" value="">
         </form> -->


        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_name" placeholder="Enter name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input_age" placeholder="Age" />
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" id="edit_user" type="submit">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<li>
  <%= userlist[i].name %>:
    <%= userlist[i].age %> <a class="delete_user" data-id="<%= userlist[i]._id %>" href="#" id="delete" title="Delete this User">Delete</a> || <a href="#openModal" class="update_user" data-target="#openModal" data-toggle="modal" id="update" title="Update user info" data-id="<%= userlist[i]._id %>">Update</a>
</li>
<%} %>
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Instead of $(document).on('click'  you can use $(document).ready(function() { $(.update).on('click'); });

Comment: @JalayOza I have tried that. The code in my js file is inside .ready. i havent posted that.

Comment: try using ```===``` instead of ```==```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(".update").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $('#edit_user').unbind('click');
    $('#edit_user').click(function() { //click on save changes button


      var user_name = $("#input_name").val();
      var user_age = $("#input_age").val();

      if (user_name == '' && user_age == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Fields");
        return false;
      }

      var user_data = {
        user_name: user_name,
        user_age: user_age
      };


      $.ajax({
        url: '/users/update_user',
        type: 'post',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user_data),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
          console.log(data);
          load_users();
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      });

    });

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It did not work still. I have added the EJS file for reference. Please take a look if you can.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Also i couldn't spot the changes you have made.

Comment: Hi Arjun, as you can see in code I have use click event $(".update").click that is the change you can see jsfiddle which I have given you https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/szufxo3r/ , click on update and click on save changes you will get alert

Comment: Hi Jalay, it works in JSFiddle, however i have entirely used your code and still doesnt function. Also i cannot find the mentioned click event $(".update").click in your JSFiddle too. Your answer consists of the change you mentioned, but the JSFiddle code is exactly like my previous code and works still.

Comment: Have you added jquery.min.js?

Comment: I have added jquery-3.2.1.min.js, bootstrap.min.js and code works

Comment: check jquery version bro, it may conflict with bootstrap